# Embedding a .app file in a Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, preview

Is it possible to "embed" an application (like Preview, Pages etc) into a Cocoa application? I would like to allow a user to view a PDF in my app with options to show/hide annotations, change the zoom level between page width and full page etc.

Is it possible to embed the Preview app within my Cocoa application? Couldn't find anything in the document or on the Internet which would suggest I could, so not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by «embedding»? An app like preview.app is present on the OS, so you just need to launch it... No need to embed it...

Comment: While it might be technically possible(?), I agree with @Macmade, plus you'd be on dodgy ground if you copied something like Preview inside your app., then distributed it right? Overkill too. Whether on the Mac or iOS there are frameworks to integrate 'previewing' PDF's in this case right inside your own app. And of course one app can launch say Preview from itself.

Comment: Thanks. Don't want the user to be able to just preview PDFs. That can as well be done in a webview. I want them to be able to add annotations, change the zoom level etc. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed an other application in the bundle of your application.
You will usually do this to embed an other application you also created, like an helper, or a daemon. It sometimes is helpful, but doesn't seem to be what you want.

If you want to let the user play with a pdf inside your application, read the [PDF Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html).
Especially look into the class `PDFView`. You can drag and drop an instance into your xib, and load content into it with this code (from Apple documentation):

```
PDFDocument *pdfDoc;

pdfDoc = [[[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [self fileName]]] autorelease];
[pdfView setDocument: pdfDoc];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed an application into another application. You can bundle it into your bundle, but it remains a separate application that will run separately. (And in the case of Preview, you'd be violating Apple's copyright, plus it'd be pointless since it comes with the OS anyway.)

When you want to do something that another application does, you have several choices:

- Use the framework(s) that that application is based on, where applicable. Only works for apps like Preview and TextEdit that are little more than application hosts for OS frameworks. Preview = ImageKit + PDFKit; TextEdit = AppKit text-rendering classes; AppleScript Editor = OSAKit.
- Farm out the job to the application. For example, you could generate the PDF as a file somewhere and open it in Preview (the one that came with the OS).
- Reinvent the wheel. Can be undesirable for obvious reasons, but can also be preferable if the existing wheel is overkill or not really a good fit for your application.

In this case, I'd go with PDFKit.